# Repeater with expand on table rows asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I am trying to use table rows with headers and all that and when the user clicks any of the rows the row should expand..

This works:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterShowCases">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="table table-responsive">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Assigned User</th>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1 class="click">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelId" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"id").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>

                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCreatedDate" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CreatedDate").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                        </h1>

                        <div class="expand">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AssignedToUser").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

But this dosent:

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterShowCases">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table class="table table-responsive">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Assigned User</th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                    <h1 class="click">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelId" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"id").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCreatedDate" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CreatedDate").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </h1>

                    <div class="expand">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AssignedToUser").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </tr>               
 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I looks likte the table data kills the expand function..

Becasue i want it all look like a table and to get more information on a specific row the user can click it and the row expands with the info..

I know i dont have data to all of the header yet but this what im testing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the markup, with labels left out, of row from your second snippet:

```
<tr>
    <h1>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </h1>
    <div></div>
</tr>
```

This is a wrong markup for a table. `tr` cannot have arbitrary tags as children, only `td` are valid there. It looks like this mixture breaks the way browser processes this table.

Your first try however is a valid markup, so you should consider following that approach. Or, if for some reason it does not work for you, your options are:

1. Get rid of tables and render everything in div's and h1's. Will require some effort to align properly, but will not have a limitation of tables in terms of markup.
2. Use colspans and rowspans, perhaps add alternating rows as needed.

Also, don't you need a footer template to close `</table>`?

Comment: Sorry dont know what happend there.. i have corrected that issue in the post.. now it looks like what i have tested 
I havent needed a footer template Before.. well i havent used the repeater like this Before.. so i dont know.. :)

Comment: @Tom, but just out of common sense, you have an opening tag for table, so you should have a closing one as well, right?

Comment: You are right, I will look in to that and add one! Need too fix the expand issue first :)

Comment: @Tom, alright, so let me see if I understand the problem. The markup issue I spotted was kind of a typo, right? The real problem then is the fact that expand script is not working with new markup. In which way is it not working?

Comment: Yes thats right.. to both questions.. I want to be able to exband each row to show more information about the row. I want to have textboxes and such.. but thats not a problem. Becuse it work if i put all in a <td> like in my post it works..

Comment: @Tom, ah, finally understood the problem. Updated my answer. Actually I should have realized that right away. It looks like your first approach is the best option you have

Comment: Thx for the awnser! I will look in too that tomorow. :)